# React child state update based on parent's prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement minesweeper with React. I have a Header component (not shown) where the dimensions and the number of bombs can be changed so the App component state (`sizeX`, `sizeY` and `bombNumber`) will be updated, and these values will be sent down to the `Table` component as props.

My problem is that the `Table` component state is dependent on `App` component's props and when the `createTable()`method gets invoked on prop updates it uses the updated `sizeX` and `sizeY` props (which is good of course) but for some reason it uses the previous value of the `bombNumber` prop.

Is this the right approach? If so what did I miss?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    sizeX: DEFAULT_SIZE,
    sizeY: DEFAULT_SIZE,
    maxBombNumber: DEFAULT_BOMB_NUMBER,
    bombNumber: DEFAULT_BOMB_NUMBER

  }

  updateSize (val, side) {
    this.setState({[side]: val}, function () {
      this.setState({maxBombNumber: this.calculateMaxBombNumber()}, function () {
        if (this.state.maxBombNumber < this.state.bombNumber) {
          this.setState({bombNumber: this.state.maxBombNumber}, function (){
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Table 
          sizeX={this.state.sizeX}
          sizeY={this.state.sizeY}
          bombNumber={this.state.bombNumber}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Table.js

```
class Table extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    table: this.createTable()
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({table: this.createTable()});
  }

  createTable() {
    // function using sizeX, sizeY and bombNumber
  }
}
```

Update:

The console log here prints the right values if I change the state, but the child will use the old value for `bombNumber`.

```
updateSize (val, side) {
  this.setState({[side]: val}, function () {
    this.setState({maxBombNumber: this.calculateMaxBombNumber()}, function () {
      if (this.state.maxBombNumber < this.state.bombNumber) {
        this.setState({bombNumber: this.state.maxBombNumber}, function (){
          console.log(this.state);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this condition works correct and how you expect?

`if (this.state.maxBombNumber < this.state.bombNumber) {
          this.setState({bombNumber: this.state.maxBombNumber});
}`

My concern is that this condition not pass and depends on your previous (initial) value in state.

Comment: I think so, if the limit is `maxBombNumber` and the current `bombNumber` is greater then it should be decreased.

Comment: "but for some reason it uses the previous value of the bombNumber prop." – if not you have prev bombNumber value? that's it? Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: The updates happen latter then it should. The state will get set properly but by that time rendering has happened. It should be some lifecycle/setState timing issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap all setState calls in one:

```
updateSize(val, side) {
    const maxBombNumber = this.calculateMaxBombNumber();
    const bombNumber = maxBombNumber < this.state.bombNumber ? maxBombNumber : this.state.bombNumber;
    this.setState({ 
        [side]: val,
        maxBombNumber,
        bombNumber
    });
}
```

UPD:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({table: this.createTable()});
  }
```

When Table component get new props from parent App –> componentWillReceiveProps execute and this.createTable() method use previous values not that in nextProps. In this way you should give it properly by arguments to createTable for example. Check this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3306l6z63).

UPD 2:

It will be better to make Table component – dump (stateless) and use state only in parent component App. Just move `createTable` method to App and it will be enough.

Or you can call createTable inside render method of Table.

Comment: I must say I'm confused by this behavior myself. I tried a codepen with only one `setState` call but it only works starting from the second call: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vqvkv4pon

Comment: I updated the original code. I think the problem somehow is that the `setState` doesn't fire right away but gets in a queue and the state actually gets set after the values are sent to the child.

Comment: I am also not sure if my code is the right way to use react as within the parent the state values are dependent on each other, and the child is also dependent on that state via props.

Comment: @MarioF i tried to fixed your code - now it works like we expect.

Comment: @chuve what was the error? I guess you cannot edit my own playground, did you fork it?

Comment: @MarioF I think it was forked automatically – https://codesandbox.io/s/z3306l6z63

Comment: Oh I see the error now, forgot to use `nextProps`. Thanks!

Comment: I tried with your first update approach and apparently it's working. I don't get it though as I have already tried this and got some errors before. Likely I should have kept all the state logic in the App component as you say.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that `setState` is an asynchronous call, so the `this.state` that you're using is not updated. See this article for more information about using `setState` with a function. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

I think this would get you what you want:

```
updateSize(val, side) {
    this.setState({ [side]: val }, function () {
        this.setState({ maxBombNumber: this.calculateMaxBombNumber() }, this.setState(function (state) {
            if (state.maxBombNumber < state.bombNumber) {
                this.setState({ bombNumber: state.maxBombNumber }, function () {
                    console.log(state);
                });
            }
        }));
    });
}
```